# Execute section of SQL based on presense of a linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query that can run on different servers. One way I'm trying to detect which server i'm on is the presense of a certain linked server (i.e. Server1 will have a link to Server2 and vice versa).

Trouble is, I can't get SQL Server to ignore/skip the code that runs on the non-existant linked server. There are two nearly identical sections of code, one which uses the Linked Server1 and one which does not (because it's running on Server1 already).

```
drop table #origdates
if exists(select 1 from sys.servers where name = N'Server1')
BEGIN
Select * into #origdates from openquery([Server1],'Select accounts, dates from table1')                                
END

if not exists(select 1 from sys.servers where name = N'Server1')
BEGIN
Select accounts, dates into #origdates from table1
END
```

If I execute the individual sections, everything is fine; the code either executes or not as specified, but the moment I run the entire thing together it's as if the server ignores the if exists section, with an error like:

```
Could not find server 'Server1' in sys.servers. Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.
```

The reason I'm doing this is so I don't have to maintain two identical scripts with two separate begginning sections.

Using ELSE in place of the second if not exists line results in the server complaining that the #origdates table already exists, even if a drop table command is issued right before the line of the select into command.

Using different table names returns the error to the 'Could not find server' message, despite that it's not even supposed to be executing that code at all...

Comment: Have you tried using ELSE instead of the second IF?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Comment: If I do the ELSE, I can't end the IF and let the rest of the script execute (the rest of the script is supposed to execute for both servers)

Comment: The way I read that, either one will execute or the other.

Comment: That's correct, in theory, but in practice it's not working that way...

Comment: Replacing the second if exists statement with ELSE results in the server complaining that the table #origdates already exists.

Comment: Check for table existence, drop if exists, then insert new data.

Comment: Never works for me: if OBJECT_ID('#origdates') is not null drop table #origdates

Comment: Use `if object_id('tempdb..#origdates') is not null drop table #origdates`

Comment: tempdb..#origdates is what you want to put in there.  Otherwise, it looks in dbo (assuming default schema of dbo).

Comment: Yes, that version right before the select into statement still doesn't fix it. Even a drop table (without the if is not null) won't let it go. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, SQL is trying to validate the `OPENQUERY`, but it can't because [Server1] is not a valid linked server.  Hiding the `OPENQUERY` in a variable should fix it.

Note, you need to pass `FROM db.owner.table` in an `OPENQUERY`, not just `FROM table`

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

if object_id('tempdb..#origdates') is not null
    drop table #origdates

create table #origdates (accounts int, dates datetime)

if exists(select 1 from sys.servers where name = N'Server1')
BEGIN
    set @sql='insert into #origdates Select * from openquery([Server1],''select accounts, dates from db.dbo.table1'')'
    exec(@sql)
END

else
BEGIN
    insert into #origdates Select accounts, dates from table1
END
```

Comment: Nice! Didn't think about hiding the query as a string!

Comment: I think you will find that `#origdates` is out of scope if the first branch of the `If` statements runs.

Comment: Yep.  That should work.  Gotta be careful about the code being run simultaneously by different users, though.

Comment: Happilly, it seems it is in scope (even if it should be logically). I flipped both sections and it seems to be working as written now. :)

Comment: @DMason true, if in a multi-user scenario, a better solution is build the #table in the current spid, and insert into in the IF/ELSE.

Comment: Edited -- be sure your `CREATE` statement matches your data types, I just picked arbitrary types.

Comment: Perhaps that's why the server was complaining that the table already existed, it assumed I had made it from the earlier section? Seems to work well with a precreated table.